# Bug or feature: why SObject[] is instance of SObject?

Tags: apex, sobject, object

Run this in Execute Anonymous

```
system.debug( new SObject[]{}  instanceof SObject );
```

> "compileProblem": "Operation instanceof is always false since an
> instance of List is never an instance of SObject"

Good to know this. But now try that:

```
Object o1 = new Integer[]{};
Object o2 = new SObject[]{};
system.debug( o1  instanceof Integer ); // ==> false, as expected
system.debug( o2  instanceof SObject ); // ==> true !!!
```

That `Integer[]` is not an instance of `Integer` sounds reasonable. But why the heck `SObject[]` is an instance of `SObject`??

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: I've raised this internally as a bug (W-10129413). SObject[] should be be an instanceOf SObject when passed via an Object.

Answer (score 3):

It's primarily a feature. It allows you to assign a query to a sObject, as in:

```
Account a = [select Id from account];
```

Unfortunately, this can introduce bugs. Make sure you check if the variable is a list before checking if a variable is an sObject.

Comment: Given how many, um, "special" cases there are in Apex I am surprised they needed instanceof to behave this way to support the assignment. The other thing I have always felt is a very silly effect of such an assignment is an error when the list of SObject instances is empty. Why on earth not just assign null?!

Comment: @PhilW I agree. I recall running into this once a long time ago, it's terribly frustrating. And yes, I think they should remove the exceptions. It'd allow millions of lines of code to be cleaned up, rather than the assign-to-list/check-if-not-empty/get-first-value or try/query/catch patterns we've had to endure since 2007.